# Epsilon-delta limits approaching negative infinity

Tags: limits, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. I want that $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = 3$. Does the following statement show that this is true?

$\forall \space \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \space M > 0$ such that $x \leq M \implies f(x) - 3 \leq \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, first your $M$ must be allowed to be negative (otherwise you can't go as far as you want toward $-\infty$), secondly what you saying is that $f(x)\leqslant 3+\varepsilon$ for $x$ small enough, you have to bound $f(x)$ from below as well (your sentence works for all function such that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)\leqslant 3$). The right sentence is
$$ \forall \varepsilon>0,\,\exists M\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall x\leqslant M,|f(x)-3|\leqslant\varepsilon \text{ (that is to say } 3-\varepsilon\leqslant f(x)\leqslant 3+\varepsilon \text{ )} $$